# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, google-maps, android-fragments

I want to display Google map in android application. I have done following steps.

1. Created a new android application project with the package name com.gaurav.googlemap
2. Downloaded Google Play Services SDK from SDK Manager
3. Imported 'google-play-services_lib' into current workspace
4. Linked 'google-play-services_lib' to my current project

   (Project properties -> Android -> Add(Into Library Section) -> Selected 'google-play-services_lib'-> Apply -> Ok
5. Registered SHA-1 fingerprint with following command

   keytool -list -v -keystore "%USERPROFILE%.android\debug.keystore" -alias    androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
6. Generated Android API key from Google API console
7. Modified AndroidManifest.xml as below

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   ```

   ```
   <uses-sdk
       android:minSdkVersion="16"
       android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

   <permission 
       android:name="com.gaurav.googlemap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
       android:protectionLevel="signature"></permission>
   <uses-permission 
       android:name="com.gaurav.googlemap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

   <uses-feature 
       android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
       android:required="true"/>

   <application
       android:allowBackup="true"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
       <meta-data
           android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
           android:value="AIzaSyC3hd_PcjjfraFGfnx3UVi0FLO5AwgxFT8" />
       <activity
           android:name=".MainActivity"
           android:label="@string/app_name" >
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>
       </activity>
   </application>
   ```
8. Modified activity_main.xml as below

   ```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   tools:context="com.gaurav.googlemap.MainActivity" >


   <fragment 
       android:id="@+id/map"
       class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
   ```
9. Modified MainActivity.java as below

   package com.gaurav.googlemap;

   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.view.Menu;
   import android.view.MenuItem;
   import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
   import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

   public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
       getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
       return true;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
       // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
       // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
       int id = item.getItemId();
       if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
           return true;
       }
       return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
   }
   ```

   }
10. And finally I ran project into Android emulator

But there is a exception in LogCat as below

```
02-14 16:41:46.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1260): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gaurav.googlemap/com.gaurav.googlemap.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class fragment
```

I have read many answers on similar questions, but I didn't get this problem fix.
I am having operating system Windows 8.1 (32-bit)

I have heard there is a different way to setup emulator to display Google map. Is this related to my problem?

Please help me to fix this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Post the code of your activity

Comment: Has this class been added/imported into your project?  Some of the links online say you need to also add google play services.

Comment: Add this in AndroidManifest.xml `<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />`

Comment: Does it require Google APIs SDK?

Comment: Added it in answer, accept it as answered as it worked for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Comment: please share the reason as well.