# Inflater working on emulator, but not on real device

Tags: android, fragment, layout-inflater, binary-xml

I'm fairly new to android app development, I'm doing it now for my project on faculty in Android Studio (using API 23). I'll go straight to the point: Application that I'm developing works (is not showing any fatal errors) on emulator when I run it, but as soon as I run it on actual device, it crashes with error "Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class fragment".

Full stack trace:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.dule.trackerapp/com.example.dule.trackerapp.LokacijaActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class fragment
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2338)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2388)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:148)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1319)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5478)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:875)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:691)
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class fragment
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:839)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:745)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1915)
     at com.example.dule.trackerapp.LokacijaActivity.onCreate(LokacijaActivity.java:39)
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5234)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2388) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:148) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1319) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5478) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:875) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:691) 
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: name == null
     at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:354)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:491)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.isSupportFragmentClass(Fragment.java:457)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2248)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:111)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:314)
     at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:31)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:79)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:839) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:745) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267) 
     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1915) 
     at com.example.dule.trackerapp.LokacijaActivity.onCreate(LokacijaActivity.java:39) 
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5234) 
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2388) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:148) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1319) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5478) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:875) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:691) 
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Full code for that activity:

```
public class LokacijaActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    //inicijalizacija promenljivih
    public GoogleMap mMapa;
    public double sirina, duzina;
    public static final String SIRINA = "SIRINA";
    public static final String DUZINA = "DUZINA";
    public File sacuvano = new File("PODACI.txt");

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lokacija);

        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) this.getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapa);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        EditText editTextSirina = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSirina);
        EditText editTextDuzina = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDuzina);
        editTextSirina.setText(String.valueOf(sirina));
        editTextDuzina.setText(String.valueOf(duzina));
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map)
    {
        mMapa = map;
        setUpMap();
    }

    private void setUpMap() {
        try {
            mMapa.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
        catch (SecurityException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        try
        {
            final Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            if (myLocation != null) {
                mMapa.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
                sirina = myLocation.getLatitude();
                duzina = myLocation.getLongitude();
            }
            else {
                LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                        sirina = myLocation.getLatitude();
                        duzina = myLocation.getLongitude();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

                    }
                };
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 2000, 10, locationListener);
            }
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(sirina, duzina);
            mMapa.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            mMapa.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14));
            mMapa.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(sirina, duzina)).title("Ovde ste!").snippet("Lokacija!"));
        }
        catch (SecurityException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

My layout file for that activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.dule.trackerapp.LokacijaActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_lokacija">

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/GornjiFragment"
        class="com.example.dule.trackerapp.MapaGornjiFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/gornji_fragment_layout" />

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/mapa"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.dule.trackerapp">

    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="23" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="23" />

    <permission
        android:name="package.name.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyCpAPnQXwsrHT9RCKfH4ICvZOFdAwBJEa0"/>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <uses-library
            android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <activity
            android:name=".GlavniMeniActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_glavni_meni"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.scytec.datamobile.vd.gui.android.AppPreferenceActivity" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>



        <activity
            android:name=".LokacijaActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_lokacija"
            android:parentActivityName=".GlavniMeniActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.dule.trackerapp.GlavniMeniActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".PosaljiMail"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_posalji_mail"
            android:parentActivityName=".LokacijaActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:exported="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.dule.trackerapp.LokacijaActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Please help me with that error, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: try to replace com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment with com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment

Comment: What is `com.example.dule.trackerapp.MapaGornjiFragment` class?

Comment: try this answer.http://stackoverflow.com/a/28519254/3678308 and show manifest file in your question

Comment: Check if your physical device API and emulator API are same.

Comment: com.example.dule.trackerapp.MapaGornjiFragment this represents the class for fragment above the MapFragment.

Comment: @Pankaj solved my problem, it was the difference between the API levels, I tried it on newer android version and it works. Thank you for your help. I'm new here, so I don't know how to rate your answer?